# How to make Raspberry Pi accessible as local web server?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, webserver, raspberry-pi3

I installed Apache, PHP, MYSQL and PHPmyAdmin on my Raspberry Pi. What I'm seeing is everything okay and working, I'm able to run commands from my Mac using SSH. Also local on the Raspberry Pi, `127.0.0.1` works, but I'm unable to access to the Raspberry Pi from Mac in the same WiFi-Network.
The IP-Address is correct, so I don't know, what could be the issue.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: so you can do a `curl localhost`from raspberry and it works fine, right? It could be something related to web server is listening on a loopback interface. Could you please post the output of `netstat -an| grep -i listen`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your apache configuration file? it is located in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf It will provide you with all the details you need. Also, is apache running? try `sudo apache2 service start`

Comment: I'll check later, just restored OS.